# Subclassing a UINavigationItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, subclass, uinavigationitem

I have a subclass for `navigationItem` because I want to change the text, font, color, etc. of the navigation title label.

I have the following for my `customNavigationItem.h`:

```
@interface CustomNavigationItem : UINavigationItem {

}
@end
```

and in the `customNavigationItem.m` I have just one method:

```
-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *)title{

NSLog(@"initWithTitle");

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 156, 44);

UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [DataSingleton sharedMySingleton].navigationTitleFont;
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
label.textColor = [DataSingleton sharedMySingleton].textColor;
label.text =  NSLocalizedString(@"Events", @"");  

self.titleView = label;

return self;
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
In the `UIViewController`, I initialized the navigation item in `initWithNibName`, connected it in the nib file, and put "CustomNavigationItem" as the custom class in IB.

The nslog works, but nothing else seems to be working.

Comment: Does the Navigator show up with the changes?

Comment: FYI, you're leaking that UILabel. After you use `self.titleView` to store it you should release it.

Comment: @benzado The UILabel is autoreleased on the alloc init line, it should be fine.

Comment: @Kristen Martinson, the navigationItem doesn't show any difference whatever I try

Comment: jylee since you are overloading the designated initializer, you need to call [super initWithTitle:] as @benzado added in my answer. After that post the updated code, and also add some checks that your shared singleton method isn't returning nil objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to propagate the init method to the parent class. When you name your method initWithSomething, it should be calling either:

- the designated initializer of your class on `self`, or
- in this case, this *is* the designated initializer, and so should be calling the designated initializer of the parent class, on `super`.

In this case `[super initWithTitle:]` -- something like this:

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    if((self = [super initWithTitle:title])){
        //initializer code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Otherwise, the init code of the parent class is never executed, the class won't be initialized properly, and nothing is guaranteed to work.

After you've done that, check that your text color isn't nil, or the same as background, or 0% alpha if you're still having problems.

Comment: Actually, you need to call the "designated initializer" of the parent class, sometimes plain `init` won't do.

Comment: I tried adding the `if ((self = [self init]))` in my existing code, but that doesn't seem do to anything still.

The way I initialized the items in the `UIViewController` are:
`sessionNavItemPortrait = [[CustomNavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"EventsTest"];`

Comment: I also tried `if ((self= [super init]))` if that works, but nothing happens

Comment: @jylee You need to call one of the documented init methods for `UINavigationItem`. When I look in the docs I only see `initWithTitle:`, so that's what you need to call.